# How to show json response in Swift 1.2?

Tags: swift

I have already showed json response on table view in objective c but i am unable to do with Swift.

> My JSON Response : "{"status":"success","result":[{"id":"10","name":"SRS TOWER"},{"id":"9","name":"123 Fake St - Investor 2 Eco "},{"id":"8","name":"VARDHMAN MALL"},{"id":"6","name":"GIP MALL CONSTRUCTION"}]}"

Any Help will be great

Comment: I fear that nobody uses Swift 1 anymore ;-)

Comment: Actually i am using Virtual mac on windows and it uses xcode 6

Comment: if possible pls reply in Swift 2.0

Comment: Sir, why i get down vote for my questions

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you are asking for code without any further information for example the ObjC code you are using. And basically Stackoverflow is not a code writing or code conversion service. And finally *How to parse / show json* has been asked thousands of times. Have you searched on SO?

Comment: Sir, i have searched but i am getting that proper help that's why because i am new to Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this all method are in swift 3.0 declare array

```
var allData = [AnyObject]()
```

assign value from json data

```
    let responsedata = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options:.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

    allData = dictValue.value(forKey: "result") as! [AnyObject]
    self.tableview.reloadData()
```

all table veiw datasource methods

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return allData.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    for item in cell.contentView.subviews
    {
        if item.tag == -55
        {
            item.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    let dictValue = allData[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let name = dictValue.value(forKey: "name") as! String

    let viewForAll = UIView()
    viewForAll.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 44)
    viewForAll.tag = -55
    cell.contentView.addSubview(viewForAll)

    let dateValue = UILabel()
    dateValue.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width-50, height: 44)
    dateValue.text = name
    dateValue.textAlignment = .left
    dateValue.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    dateValue.textColor = UIColor.black
    viewForAll.addSubview(dateValue)

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

Comment: how to reload table because response is dynamic

Comment: hi @DilipTiwari after this line put the code to reload tableview "allData = dictValue.value(forKey: "result") as! [AnyObject]" and its works

Comment: Ok Sir, Did i need to removeAllobjects from array and add objects to array

Comment: @DilipTiwari allData = dictValue.value(forKey: "result") as! [AnyObject], here we assign the array everytime get the response so no need to remove any object

Comment: Sir, you want i will show my objective c code for the above JSON reponse which works perfectly

Comment: thanks for your answer it works and if possible how can i connect to you personally and i really thank you for your efforts

Comment: @DilipTiwari If my answer works then please accept my answer and  i am glad to help you!

Comment: i accepted your answer and it is working fine for me

Comment: May i take your help anytime

Comment: How can i chat personally because i am new to Swift and this is my first project which i am working.

Comment: @DilipTiwari Yeah sure but please accept my answer first so it would be good for other also

Comment: @DilipTiwari Welcome mate Happy coding!